# DataGridViewComboBoxCell Readonly but set my combobox to default value instead of making it disable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a DGV that have a ComboBoxColumn, the data in the combobox is from a data table. Also this dataGridview has a button and the button will be disable depend on the value of the comboBox. If Combobox Value = Tree a showdialog will show and if the user ok the value of the combobox will be readonly.

My code works fine but when i add this to disable the combobox it removes the value that i selected in the combobox and set the combobox to readly.

`dgvtree.Rows(_priIndex).Cells("tree").ReadOnly = True`

What i want to happen is the combobox will be readonly when user click ok and the selected item in the combobox will be there but readonly.

Comment: I have never experienced, that changing the readonly property also effects the value. could you post more source code please